# LogicException: The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected

Tags: caching, drupal

Drupal :9.5.9

Module : Rest Block Layout

Issue when Api call  /block-layout?_format=json&path=/test It is giving Below error message . Previously on drupal 8.7.5 it is working fine but after version updation it is giving error. Let me know if anyone has solution how to fix it .

```
Error Message : LogicException: The controller result claims to be providing 

> relevant cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected. Please
> ensure you are not rendering content too early. Returned object class:
> Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse. in
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext()
> (line 158 of
> \core\lib\Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php).
```

I have applied below mentioned patch but from below patch error is gone , but in my website if user view multiple pages in separate tabs it is showing wrong node content data. It shows data which was latest cached.

```
"drupal/core": {
                "#2638686-43 Issue cache leaked metadata": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-09-10/2638686-43.patch"
            },
```